# How to create a JavaScript that clicks a particular URL after a certain amount of delay?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to create a JavaScript that clicks a particular LINK after a certain amount of delay say e.g. 10 seconds on an HTML page.

Can you please provide me with the JavaScript, please? What I only managed to find after doing a search on Google is click a particular LINK but without a delay.

Can you help me please?

Thanks.

Comment: you are doing code hunting. please do your homework yourself and come with concrete questions

Answer (score 3):

Include this method (however you want):

```
function fireEvent(element,event) { 
   if (document.createEvent) { 
       // dispatch for firefox + others 
       var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents"); 
       evt.initEvent(event, true, true ); // event type,bubbling,cancelable 
       return !element.dispatchEvent(evt); 
   } else { 
       // dispatch for IE 
       var evt = document.createEventObject(); 
       return element.fireEvent('on'+event,evt) 
   } 
}
```

Then call it:

```
window.setTimeout(function() { 
    var e = document.getElementById('yourLinkId');
    if(e) fireEvent(e, 'click');

}, 10000);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    window.location = "http://your_url_here.com";
}, 10000);
```

The second parameter is the time in milliseconds. So 10000 milliseconds is 10 seconds.

Comment: Hi Arjun, Thanks for the help. What I meant was a particular link on the webpage rather than a URL, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: if you found how to click a particular link on google, why can't you substitute what you found in the code. Replace the `window.location = ` with what you have

Comment: I want it to click this particular link on the page after a delay rather than as it loads.

Comment: You're being incredibly vague.  Javascript isn't for activating page content like that.  What you CAN do is ask the link (the `<a>` tag) for its source attribute and use window.location on that.  I'd VERY much recommend doing your homework before asking this thread how to do that, so far we've given you answers that are RIDICULOUSLY well documented across the internet; it makes it pretty clear that you didn't even make an attempt to solve this one.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the delay something like the one shown on this [site](http://www.subhashsarees.com/listing_products.aspx) (See the "Testimonials" container at the bottom-left corner of the page), use the following jQuery code.

```
(function($){
$(document).ready(function(){
    var el = $("#testimonial"); //The id of the container. It may be a `<div>`
    if (el){
    RotateTestimonial();
    setInterval(RotateTestimonial, 20000);
    }
});

function RotateTestimonial(){
    var pageUrl = "RandomTestimonial.jsp"  //The page where the request goes.
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: pageUrl,
            cache:false,
            success: function(msg) {                   
                $("#testimonial").slideUp('slow').fadeOut(3000, function (){
                    var el = $("#testimonial"); 
                    el.html(msg);
                    el.slideDown('slow').fadeIn('slow');
                });
            }
    });
}
})(jQuery)
```