# Playing piano keys after delay in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, keypress

I was trying to write a script to 'play' some keys on [this online keyboard](http://www.p-ano.com/p-ano.html) by using JavaScript to 'click' the keys for me.

## The code

```
//sample array to iterate over
var keys_ = ['et', 'dst', 'et', 'dst', 'et', 'b', 'dt', 'ct', 'a', ...];

//handles the clicking only
function playKey(id_) {
    key_ = document.getElementById(id_);
    key_.click(); }

//iterates over the array
function playKeys(keys_) {
    delay = 1000;
    for (i = 0; i < keys_.length; i++) {
        console.log(delay);
        key_ = keys_[i];
        console.log(key_);
        window.setTimeout('playKey(key_)', delay);
        delay += 1000; 
        } 
    }
```

## The output

The console throws the following error:

> 1000
>   et
>   2000
>   dst
>   ...
>   9000
>   a
>   undefined
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null p-ano.html:142
>   8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'click' of null

As you can see, the `delay` and `key_` values are perfectly correct. But still when I execute this, after a second (i.e., the 1<sup>st</sup> timeout), all the keys seem to play at once and then nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

*P.S.: I've seen other questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492116/how-to-create-a-javascript-that-clicks-a-particular-url-after-a-certain-amount-o) and searched Google and other forums, to no avail*

Answer (score 2):

Learn about closures.

```
window.setTimeout(function(){ playKey(key_); }, delay);
```

and you have a problem with globals and locals. Use var!

The way I would write it would be

```
( function() {
    var keys_ = ['et', 'dst', 'et', 'dst', 'et', 'b', 'dt', 'ct', 'a'],
        delay = 250,
        currentIndex = 0,
        playKeys = function () {
            document.getElementById(keys_[currentIndex]).click();        
            currentIndex++;
            if (currentIndex<keys_.length) {
                window.setTimeout(playKeys,delay);
            }    
        };    
    playKeys();
})();
```

Comment: Can you give me the lowdown on `closures`? (I haven't slept properly in days and don't want to Google right now)

Comment: Haven't tested your code yet, but sure that it's fine and works, but can you explain why _my_ code isn't working?

Comment: Because `key_` is evaluated with the wrong scope when the setInterval fires. Add a console.log like in `function playKey(id_) { console.log(id_);` to see what I am talking about. If you declared var for `key_`, you would have gotten a different error.

Comment: I haven't used `setInterval`, would using that have made more sense?

Comment: What's the '_scope_' of something?

Comment: What do you mean _"you declared var for key_, you would have gotten a different error"_?

Comment: You do not know what [variable scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope) is? You need to grasp that concept since it is a big part of programming.

Comment: @epascarello Sorry, I _do_ know what var scopes are from my experience in Python. Just wasn't appling them to JS. Sorry...

Answer (score 1):

Huh? There's already a built-in function called `playstr()`.

```
function playstr(instr) {
    keystr = instr;
    time = 0;
    k = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < keystr.length; i++) {
        setTimeout("playkbd(keystr[k])", time += 50);
        setTimeout("k++", time + 50);
        setTimeout("cb()", time += 200);
    }
}​
```

Try pressing 'z', 'x', or 'm' to run them.

```
if (key=="z")
  playstr("wetyuyuju     ujo..juyyuj..uyttfy..yuytft     ujp..o;poko     opoj..uy\
  uju     ujo..juyyuj..uyttfy..yuytft     w e t y u y uoj u ")

if (key=="x")
  playstr("tgtdtgtdtgghhgtdd              tgtdtgtdtgghhgtdd              djjjkjhh\
  jhghjhg djjjkjhhjhghjhg djjjkjhhjhghjhg djjjkjhhjh     tgtdtgtdtgghhgtdd")

if (key=="m")
  playstr("         k j y j k j y f e f e a e f y j k j y j k j y f e f e a e f y\
   j k j y j k j y f e f e a e f y j k j y j k j y f e f e a e f y j ")
```

I am running a [mirror](http://tinabama.com/p-ano/p-ano.html) and want to know how to auto-play chords.

```
// F F 1 F A N F A R E 

if (key==".") {
  setTimeout("playstr('u y u yo ok ok ku y g yf   u y u yo ok ok ku y u op ')",100)
}
```

Comment: @TinaCGHeehr I don't understand. What is `playstr` and if it's a built-in, what are you showing here?

Comment: Does `playkbd` simulate key presses?

Comment: What's `cb`? What's `keystr` and how does the var `k` relate to it?

Comment: Sorry, I'm so dense, but could you just explain a wee bit more? (Or maybe I'll be able to clear my head and grok the code or Google stuff myself after a proper night's sleep (I live in UTC +3:30)

Comment: OK, view the source code for p-ano.js, there's a built-in function called `playstr`. Find it with Ctrl+F. That's how the original author decided to implement what you want.

Comment: yes, please come back later when you have rested. The author has already done what you want. If you want, send me a youtube link of your song and i'll try to auto-play it :D

Comment: @TinaCGHeehr I get it, so by built-in, you meant as in the source code for the Piano app. Thanks for clearing that up. Can you explain the rest of the code to me as I'm still a newbie to JS?

Comment: I was trying to play this song: [Fur Elise](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_mVW8tgGY_w), though the real point of this was to test my scripting abilities. I always seem to learn more stuff like that...

Comment: No prob. One last thing, this solution will probably work fine all right but can you explain why _my_ code isn't working?

Comment: Go to my page and press "Z" http://tinabama.com/p-ano/p-ano.html `playstr(";p;p;jlkh adhj  dhjk d ;p;p;jlkh   adhj d kjh   jkl;");`

Comment: Continued discussion over [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16422/discussion-between-yatharthrock-and-tina-cg-hoehr)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the code you have posted is exactly what you are running. In this case the three dots are illegal.

```
keys_ = ['et', 'dst', 'et', 'dst', 'et', 'b', 'dt', 'ct', 'a', ...]
```

Try removing them like

```
keys_ = ['et', 'dst', 'et', 'dst', 'et', 'b', 'dt', 'ct', 'a']
```

Also, as a tip, try writing cleaner javascript. Use `var` before declaring variables. End your statements with `;` semi-colons.

Comment: Added the `var` before the assignments. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, why isn't `var` _required_ before assignments? Maybe to allow parallel assignments as when I run them in the console, I get different outputs.

Comment: And I'll remember the semi-colons, code readability (or rather, code _validity_) is important...

Comment: And the ellipsis were there to prevent the Wall of Text you'd get if I hadn't removed the unnecessary stuff

Comment: Considering this didn't answer my question or even try (I'm not asking about some SyntaxErrors), shouldn't this have been a comment?

Comment: I'm a newbie, so please excuse my, uh... "newbieness"

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I assumed that the code you posted was the **exact** code you were trying to run. Therefore the ellipsis would have been a reason why it was broken.